# better way to declare DateTime with 0 hours minutes and second

Tags: c#, datetime

Is there a simpler way to declare d2 ? (one line)

```
    var d1 = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-160);
    var d2 = new DateTime(d1.Year, d1.Month, d1.Day, 0, 0, 0);
```

Comment: You don't need `d2` because you have the [`Date`-property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.date?view=net-5.0). If you want today midnight you can simply use `DateTime.Today`.

Answer (score 2):

You are not obliged to provide hours/minutes/seconds and the default for them will be 0.

```
var d2 = new DateTime(d1.Year, d1.Month, d1.Day)
```

Or even better you can just extract  the date part, witch will only keep the year/month/day part.

```
var d2 = d1.Date;
```

Comment: i may have made a mistake in my question. I wan't to declare a datetime with date=now() and hour=0, minute=0 and second=0, in one line

Comment: DateTime.Today is even shorter in that case

Comment: But in your question you remove 160 days so you won't have the today's date.